# Model.get_FOO_display() method does not work when using values() QuerySets

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

In my *"models.py"* I have the following:

`class Contact(models.Model):`
    `type = models.IntegerField('Contact Type', choices=core.constants.CONTACT_TYPE_CHOICES)`

In the HTML template, as per normal, I use the following to retrieve the "human-readable" value returned from a normal QuerySet:

`{{ contact.get_type_display }}`

However, when I make use of the *"ValuesQuerySet"* as described here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values

then the _"Model.get_FOO_display()"_ method does not work anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `values()` to retrieve a subset of all possible fields, you could try using `only()` instead since it works nicely with `get_FOO_display()`

[Django documentation for only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#only)